# React Native, having many components affects performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

Regarding performance, regardless of states, function calls, data flow, etc. Is it better to subdivide as much as possible into components? I mean, for example, if in a component there is an icon that represents the back arrow button, will it be a good pattern to make an specific component for this? And would it affect performance positively or negatively?

(Suppose that this component does not seem to be used again in the entire application)

Comment: I think components should be used like functions, if you gonna use some functionallity again or is similar functionallity, make a component with its props. If not i do not think a component for a simple icon would be useful. Maybe a component for icons that render different icon depending in a prop called "iconName", that could be usefull.

Comment: Try to reduce the stateful components in your application and you will improve the performance